# Entity Framework Core linq query returns InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I am currently creating a web api in .net CORE with Entity Framework.

Whenever I try to select a single record by ID with linq, I get the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code.
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32'
>   to type 'System.Char'.

This error happens whenever I execute the following linq query:

```cs
int id = 1;
User user = context.Users.First(i => i.UserId == id);
```

I have already checked, and both field `UserId` and variable `id` are integers. Also the table contains enough elements and a row with an `id` of 1 exists.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: Here is a part of the `User` Model:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    (...)
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's enough information in the question yet to allow this question to be answered. At the very least, the table definition and class definition will be needed too.

Comment: Try using i.UserId.Equals(id) instead of i.UserId == id

Comment: @hvd I added a part of the `User` Model.

Comment: @aguafrommars I have already tried this and got exactly the same outcome.

Comment: That's part of the class definition. What's the full class definition, and what's the table definition? It could easily happen as a result of a mismatch in other columns.

Comment: It's probably because you have a property defined as `char` that's an integer in the database.

Comment: @Rob Thankyou! This was the problem. There was a property as char in my datamodel, but as integer in the database.

Comment: @Max I took the liberty of adding an actual answer that elaborates on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Note: The answer was actually provided in a comment under the original question. I'm just adding a little to it here, to make it more visible and clear.*

---

Entity Framework obviously maps C# classes to database tables via properties that represent the various columns in each table. Now if the datatype of one of these properties is not compatible with the datatype of it's corresponding column in the database, then you will get an `System.InvalidCastException` when attempting to fetch anything from that table, even if the mismatching property is not directly involved in the look-up.

In the question, the query was:

```
User user = context.Users.First(i => i.UserId == id);
```

It does not matter that both `id` and it's corresponding property `UserId` are valid and compatible with each other here, because what is being fetched is an instance of the whole class `User`.

Apparently the type of some other property in `User` is incompatible with the type a column with the same name in the `user` table in the database, and so the attempt to map to it throws the above exception.

Comment: Do you know if there's an actual way to be able to identify the column?