# When executing the linq query its throwing the casting error system.int32

Tags: c#, .net, linq, model-view-controller

```
var Appointment = (from app in _context.Appointments
                                   join pt in _context.Patients on app.PatientID equals pt.ID into 
                                   patients
                                   from pt in patients.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   join doc in _context.Doctors on app.DoctorID equals doc.ID into 
                                   doctors
                                   from doc in doctors.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                       //join offloc in _context.OfficeLocations on app.DoctorID 
                                    equals offloc.DoctorID into officlocation
                                       //from offloc in officlocation.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   join docavail in _context.DoctorsAvailabilities on 
                                   app.AvailabilityID equals docavail.ID into availability
                                   from docavail in availability.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   where ((app.CreatedByReferral == ReferralSpecialistID || 
                                   app.CompanyID == CompanyID || app.UserGroupID == CompanyID) && 
                                   app.OtherPatientID == null && pt.Status == StatusConstant.Active 
                                   && app.Status != AppointmentRescheduledID && 
                                   app.IsCloseAppointment != true)
                                   select new AppointmentDataTableResult
                                   {

                                       appointmentID = app.ID,
                                       PatientID = pt.ID,
                                       patientname = (pt.NamePrefix ?? "") + " " + pt.FirstName + " " + pt.LastName + " " + (pt.NameSuffix ?? ""),
                                       ParentPatientID = 0,
                                       dateofbirth = pt.DateOfBirth,
                                       patientType = _context.CategoryDetails.Where(x => x.ItemID == app.PatientTypeID).Select(x => x.MasterData).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       phone = pt.Phone,
                                       Date = docavail.Date,
                                       Time = docavail.Time,
                                       statustext = _context.CategoryDetails.Where(x => x.ItemID == app.Status).Select(x => x.MasterData).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       doctorname = (doc.NamePrefix ?? "") + " " + doc.FirstName + " " + doc.LastName + " " + (doc.NameSuffix ?? ""),
                                       DoctorID = doc.ID,
                                       checkin = app.CheckIn,
                                       checkout = app.CheckOut,
                                       checkintime = app.CheckInTime,
                                       checkouttime = app.CheckOutTime,
                                       withoutslot = app.WithoutSlot,
                                       locatioid = app.LocationID ?? 0,
                                       AppointmentSource = app.AppointmentSource ?? 0,
                                       Status = app.Status ?? 0,
                                       IsPastAppointment = app.IsPastAppointment,
                                       casestatusID = app.CaseStatusID ?? 0,
                                       caseTypeID = app.CaseTypeID ?? 0,
                                       ReferralAttorneyID = app.ReferralAttorneyID ?? 0,
                                       ReferralProviderID = app.ReferralProviderID ?? 0,
                                       patientTypeID = app.PatientTypeID ?? 0,
                                       InsuranceID = app.InsuranceID ?? 0,
                                       PendingAppointmentDate = app.PreferredAppointmentDateTime,
                                       // AppointmentDate = docavail.Date.Value.Month + "/" + docavail.Date.Value.Day + "/" + docavail.Date.Value.Year + " " + docavail.Time.Value.Hours + ":" + docavail.Time.Value.Minutes,
                                       ReportCount = _context.DoctorReportStatus.Where(x => x.StatusID == StatusConstant.Active && x.AppointmentID == app.ID).Count(),
                                       RerecordUploadedYN = app.RerecordUploadedYN,
                                       IsAppointmentPending = app.IsAppointmentPending,
                                       IsPendingBillingRecoardYN = app.IsPendingBillingRecoardYN,
                                       strDate = docavail.Date.Value.Month + "/" + docavail.Date.Value.Day + "/" + docavail.Date.Value.Year,
                                       DateChekin = default(DateTime),
                                       totaldays = 0
                                   });
```

Comment: It's a syntax error - you have commented the `join` but using `equals` on next line

Comment: Hello!Welcome to Stackoverflow.Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40448796/entity-framework-core-linq-query-returns-invalidcastexception

Comment: no man if it would be syntax error it won't run with other cases, its only throwing error while converting it to .tolist()

Comment: help me please, I am too blind to see. Where do you cast or convert anything to an `int32` ?

Comment: actually to be able to really help you we would need the declaration of `AppointmentDataTableResult` and all the tables that are involved to see all variables with their `Type`s. Otherwise this will remain a guessing game..... and it will probably take forever

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I also face same problem many time this problem occurs when you put `ToList` method because before putting the `ToList()` method the output generated by the query is of type `IQueryable<object>`, but this not the solution of your problem

The problem is that maybe

1. You are assigning a nullable integer type variable to non-nullable integer type value, or
2. Comparing the nullable integer value to non-nullable value in join  or vice versa

Chances of second case are greater because when assigning, the C# compiler throws an error.

Check your types of compared variable and let me give some follow ups.

Comment: i have not done both in my query , some  are nullable some are not but i have not checked nullable with non nullable

Comment: where is your "offloc" variable declared which you compared in 9th line